# Can the speed of updating rows in a Room database be improved for 100k records?

Tags: database, sqlite, android-room

I am new to databases and Android, I have followed a few tutorials online but I am stuck on this. I am trying to update 100,000 records in one statement. It is taking about 6 seconds. I need it in less than 1 :(

Dao ..

```
  @Update(entity = Bac::class)
    fun updateCombos(combo: List<Combo>)
```

Repository ..

```
suspend fun updateCombos(combo: List<Combo>) {
    bacDao.updateCombos(combo)
}
```

View model ..

```
fun updateCombos(combo: List<Combo>){
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.updateCombos(combo)
    }
}
```

Calling the function ..

```
mBacViewModel.updateCombos(updatedCombo)
```

Combo is just a data object that is a Long type, updatedCombo is a list of them all (100k). I hope I am doing something wrong and this isn't acceptable speed.

Tho I read this article and it doesn't look promising .. https://hackernoon.com/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-insertions-with-room-d769512f8330

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: After passing through same kind of problem with table of  89 columns, i dont think it will fall inside 1 second. I have indexed data which should be faster while traversing and collecting the required data through tables but writing a big chunk e.g. 50000 records for say 15 tables into list experienced OOM problem as well. In short, i adapted the serialized data feom external storage  while reading multiple chunks of data from 100K plus tables by which i have overcome my time performance.

Comment: Plus one thing you can try for is use some other data type like use some less memory occupying datatype which in turn will degrade accuracy to some extent. I changed my double to float which is acceptable in my case. It will make improvements in terms of time to some extent which you can analyze.